# Synonym request: [machine.config] and [machine-config]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I think that [machine.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine.config) should be made a synonym of [machine-config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-config). Both of these seems to address the same thing. The only difference is the hyphen and the dot in the tag names.

Since I don't have enough score on either of the tags, can someone who is capable of making those tags a synonym, do it?

Comment: All `machine.config` and `web.config` related tags: [tag:machine-config] [tag:machine.config] [tag:web-config] [tag:web.config-transform] [tag:web.config] [tag:web-config-transform] [tag:web-config-encryption] [tag:webconfigurationmanager]

Comment: Why not burninate one over the other? I woud keep machine.config and retag machine-config questions